# Simple Example using Backbone.js and Rivets.js

Tags: backbone.js, rivets.js

I am looking for a very simple example where e.g. there is a two way binding between `span` text and an `input` element using Backbone.js and [Rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/). Perhaps there is one in the Rivets.js docs, but I can't find it. Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a two-way binding (model-to-view and view-to-model) on an input element and a one-way binding (model-to-view) on a span element, then the following view will do what you describe.

```
<div id="user-view">
  <span>{ user:name }</span>
  <input rv-value="user:name">
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eH4zG/252/) that demonstrates things in action. It includes a Backbone adapter on the `:` interface and shows how to bind a model to the view (this is just a more trivial example of what is already shown on the homepage).

Comment: how do you display collections of model objects with rivets currently?

Comment: @rhodee As of **0.3.2** there is a `data-each-[item]` binding to iterate over items in an array.

Comment: @MichaelRichards can you explain why the click outside the input creates the change? how can we configure it to respond to something beside a click outside etc?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use：
https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder
It can satisfy the two-way binding between the demand of all the view and model。

This is what I do nested view binding example：
http://files.cnblogs.com/justinw/Nested_Model_bi_Binding.zip